# Volley , Wait for response to return wait until use flag

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I have to respond to result of volley request. but because it is asynchronous. I need to wait for the results before I proceed. If I don't I will get nullobjects.

How do I set flags and wait until flags are off.

```
 categoryslashid = new JSONObject[Category_IDs.size()];//size of the list containing all categories   

    taskfinished = new boolean[Category_IDs.size()];

    //boolean is initialized to false
    //Request to category/{id} to get 
    for(int i= 0;i<Category_IDs.size();i++)
    {              makevolleyrequesforCategorySlashID(Const.URL_FULL_STOREURL+Const.URL_PRODUCT_GET_CATEGORY_ID,i);
    }
public void makevolleyrequesforCategorySlashID(URL,id)
{
//volley implementation
public void onResponseoverride
{
categoryslashid[i]=response;
taskfinished[i]=true;
}

}
```

Now I must proceed after I get all the booleans in task finished become true.

```
public  boolean areAllTrue()
    {

        for(boolean b : taskfinished) if(!b) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you want. please post some code examples and be more specific about what you're trying to achieve & what's not working.

Comment: Why don't you process your things in your `onResponseoverride`?

Comment: I will try that, this is being called on an Asynctask : doinBackground() already. I will call it onCreate then?

Answer (score 4):

Implement an Interface and use it to call back when your data is ready. Something like this:

```
public interface OnDownloadTaskCompleted {
    public void onTaskCompleted(List<ofSomething> list,  boolean error, String message);
}
```

Then you should pass an instance of this to your request and override `onTaskCompleted()`

```
private void downloadData(){

        final DownloadUsingVolley downloader = new DownloadUsingVolley(getActivity());
        downloader.retrieveData(new OnDownloadTaskCompleted() {
            @Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(List<ofSomething> list, boolean error, String message) {
                //do something with your data
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm assuming that you have a class where you implemented volley stuff (DownloadusingVolley) and a method do call on it and make the request itself (retrieveData).

retrieveData can be implemented like this:

```
private void retrieveData(String url, final OnDownloadTaskCompleted taskCompleted){
    final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                //parse
                taskCompleted.onTaskCompleted(result,false,null);
            }catch (JSONException e){
                taskCompleted.onTaskCompleted(0,true,e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    },new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            taskCompleted.onTaskCompleted(0,true,volleyError.getMessage());
        }
    });
    //adding request into the queue
    ApplicationClass.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request,"aTag");
}
```

Here you can find a nice tutorial about volley: 
[Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Android Using Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)