# Get value for volley request to finish before proceeding with method? Android Java

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-volley

its my first time asking a question here, so please tell me if I missed to include something.

I have a method that prints returns a String. Inside it, is an asychronous volley request that retrieves a specific value to be added to the String. The problem is that the request is made, but since it's an asynchronous request, the method still proceeds and returns the String even if it still doesn't have the value from the request. The request completes afterwards. So the question is, is there a way to make the method wait for a specific variable to have a value before proceeding, without freezing the UI? Should I create a new thread instead?

Code below is not the actual codes I have but it shows the outline.

```
public String getStr{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String strOne;

    // code here..

    // asynchronous request here..

    // code here..
    sb.append(strOne)
    // code here..

    return sb.toString();
}
```

The ***asychronous request*** refers to the volley request.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's a "volley" request?

Comment: @mjuarez - The volley request I'm referring to is a JSONObject request using volley library. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should handle the response in onResponse (@Override) method. Take a look in this tutorial:

[Asynchronous HTTP Requests in Android Using Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)

If you want to return the response to another class to handle it there, I suggest you to implement an interface. I could post the code for this here, but I aswered a question like this here:

[Volley , Wait for response to return wait until use flag - answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058778/volley-wait-for-response-to-return-wait-until-use-flag/29062826#29062826)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. :) I already have a similar implementation as to what you are suggesting. I am able to retrieve the data that I need via the request, it just that the method still proceeds (because the request is asynchronous) so the data I need to add to a String is null if returned.

Comment: But if you're using a callback you should put the methods that need the string inside it (callback) and call your callback inside the overrided method onResponse from volley. Actually, it works perfectly like this... You have to deal with async stuff using callbacks...